# Open text input on touch monitor in windows 7 using html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, touch, nui

Don't know if this question has been brought up, but did a quick search and didn't find anything of interest. My question is regarding using a touch screen conected to a windows 7 monitor, if you for example use google crome and click on the address field (using the touch monitor) the keyboard symbol is brought up (see image). Can I do this in html? Say that when I click on a text input field in a webpage that the same symbol arries under the text input field?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an OS/browser problem, not an HTML/JS problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the preffered sollution to my problem using hot virtual keyboard.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcYEFk6_5GQ